# Vim: execute paragraph in shell

Tags: bash, vim, terminal

I'd like to execute a paragraph from a shell file when I browse it in Vim.

```
yap: exec "!" . @"
```

is an approach that would work when all newlines are already escaped with  \ , what they aren't.

Another approach would be

```
"*yap: !bash <CR><S-Ins><CR>
```

when I do it by hand all newlines are escaped automatically. But I am unable to automate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpler:

```
vap:write !bash
```

This works because `:write` can take a file argument, or a `!cmd` argument, in which case the text of the file (or the text selected by the range, which is the paragraph when coming out of visual mode) is provided on stdin to `cmd`

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using contents of the default register, this calls a function that takes a range.

```
function! Run() range
  echo system(join(getline(a:firstline, a:lastline), "\n"))
endfunction
```

So select your paragraph `vap` and then run `:'<,'>call Run()`

Comment: @D.BenKnoble [`system()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#system()) surely uses a shell, what's the problem?

Comment: @phd woops :P I always associate system functions like that as bypassing the shell and exec’ing commands directly. Perhaps that’s plain wrong; at least for vim it is. Apologies.